# AWS EFS too slow when i use git & npm install

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I'm using aws S3 storage and cloudfront for my dozens of static web sites.
Also i'm using aws lambda with nodejs and EFS for git, node_modules and build cache files.

When i try `git clone`, `npm install` and `npm run build` from EFS it's working to slow.
But when i try from lambda `/tmp` folder it's working x10 faster than the EFS storage.

I need a storage like EFS because i storage dozens of web sites git, node package and cache files. So how can i increase EFS performance.

Comment: Can I ask why do the files need to be on EFS. If you could provide more information on the usecase it would help :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Thanks for your comment. I'm building my sites with gatsbyjs. It runs the aws-lambda "npm run build" command for each site that needs to be built. I chose EFS because I needed a storage where I needed to keep the files previously installed with git clone and npm install.

Comment: In my previous role we decided against using EFS for a kubernetes gitlab deployment because for gitlab\git EFS is not recommended: "Customers and users have reported that AWS EFS does not perform well for GitLab’s use-case. Workloads where many small files are written in a serialized manner, like git, are not well-suited for EFS. EBS with an NFS server on top will perform much better." Instead we opted for an using EBS volume. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/nfs.html Are you not able to use code commit for your repos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have used the standard settings for EFS you will be utilizing burstable credits which are depleted the more file changes you make.

Depending on the file size and the number of changes on the EFS mount you nay be depleting the available credits which would provide performance problems for any application attached to the EFS mount. You can detect this by looking at the `BurstCreditBalance` CloudWatch metric, also keep an eye for any flatlining of `TotalIOBytes` as this might suggest it has reached its maximum throughput.

When you perform the git clone you could also use the `--depth` with a value of `1` to create a shallow clone. This option will get only the latest commit, as opposed to cloning the entire git history too.

A improvement to this workflow I would suggest reconsidering to use the following technologies to provide the workflow for what you want. Rather than a Lambda function create a [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) pipeline that will trigger a [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) job. This CodeBuild job would be responsible for running the npm install task for you as well as any other actions.

Part of CodePipeline's flow is that it will store the legacy artifact in S3 along the way, so that you have a copy of it. The CodePipeline can also deploy to your S3 bucket as well at the end.

A couple of links that might be useful for you:

- [AWS EFS Performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html)
- [Tutorial: Create a pipeline that uses Amazon S3 as a deployment provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-s3deploy.html)

Comment: This suggestion is exactly what I have gone with, github for source code and a code pipeline primarily consisting of a set of codebuild jobs and a custom build agent with common code wrapped up in it. Works very well aside from the fact that code pipeline needs to know about branches in advance which means I only have a pipeline for master, and rely on a couple of code build jobs to handle feature branch push and pull request webhooks,

Comment: @berimbolo CodePipeline is tied to a single branch but CodeBuild is not. If you use CodeBuild directly, you can build from any git commit/branch.

Comment: Yes I know, and I do use (as I mentioned) code build jobs alone for feature push and PR, which is prior to my change merging into master, once merged into master I then trigger a code pipeline on master.... running code builds outside of a pipeline will only get me so far, for instance a manual approval stage or wanting to easily chain together code builds is easily done using code pipeline...

Answer (score 0):

EFS with git, regardless of config is not working very well.

However, `rsync` works much better.
As such a workaround for EFS+git repo that worked for me:

1. Clone to an EBS.
2. Rsync to the EFS

Despite the extra step, this seems to perform dramatically better.